# setIgnoresMouseEvents Exception

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want to be able to call setIgnoresMouseEvents on my NSWindow but I want to have an exception to where I can still click a button on the window and it will work but everything else ignores the mouse events, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subclass the application or the window, and override `sendEvent:`. Upon every mouse event, use `-[NSEvent locationInWindow]`, `-[NSEvent window]`, `-[NSView hitTest:]` to check if the click would go the desired button, and ignore it (return without calling `super`) if it wouldn't. (I didn't try it, but it seems quite straightforward).